# postgresql 9.1 Multiple Cluster on same host

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 cluster databases, running on the same host, Ubuntu. My fist database port is set to default but my second database port is set to 5433 in the postgresql.conf file. While everything is ok with local connections, I cannot connect using any of my tools to the second database with port 5433, including pgAdmin. Please help. Any parameter that I need to modify for the new database with port 5433?

`netstat -an | grep 5433` shows,

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5433 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 :::5433 :::* LISTEN 
unix 2 [ ACC ] STREAM LISTENING 72842 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433
```

`iptables -L` shows,

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Have you opened access to that port through any firewall (iptables)?  Is it definitely listening on that port on an external interface?  What does `netstat -an | grep 5433` show.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5433                 :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     72842    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433

Comment: So, it's listening, you can connect locally - your next check is your firewall.  Have you allowed port 5433 through iptables.

Comment: no i didn't do that. how can i do this?

Comment: Post the output of `iptables -L` and someone who knows `iptables` better than me can help.  Add the output to your question, not in a comment (like I did with your `netstat` output).

Comment: Re-post of http://serverfault.com/questions/439867/postgresql-error-connecting-to-a-cluster ?

Comment: How do you try to connect?  Could you show us your connection string?

Comment: Did this recently stop working, or is the second cluster a new thing that's never worked right?

Comment: Can you include error messages please?

Answer (score 1):

First, please post error messages.  Otherwise this is shooting in the dark.

You could have a bunch of problems.  I would suggest the following:

1. If you simply get a connection refused, try netstat -p | grep 5433 so you can see what programs are listening on the port.  Is it something unexpected?
2. If you are getting pg_hba.conf errors, double check your settings there.
3. Please check again your listen settings in your postgresql.conf file.
4. Check your postgresql log on the cluster you are having trouble with.  Please post relevant sections if this doesn't get you to your answer.